# how to get class info. in attribute class which is written on that class

Tags: model-view-controller, attributes

[myattribute]
class myclass
{

}

myattribute:attribute
{

// here i need to access all properties with values and methods of "Myclass".

}

how can i get this..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Reflection...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28VS.71%29.aspx